# PowerShell script to get network card speed of a Windows Computer

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

What is the PowerShell script to get the speed a specific Windows machine's network card is running at?

I know this can be done with a WMI query based statement and will post an answer once I work it out.

Answer (score 9):

A basic command is

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName 'servername' -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter | `
    Where-Object { $_.Speed -ne $null -and $_.MACAddress -ne $null } | `
    Format-Table -Property SystemName,Name,NetConnectionID,Speed
```

Note that the ComputerName parameter takes an array so you can run this against multiple computers provided you have rights. Replace the Format-Table property list with ***** to get a more comprehensive list of available properties. You might want to filter on these properties to get rid of entries you aren't interested in.

Using the built in byte Multiplier suffixes (MB, GB etc) would also make the speed more readable depending on your needs. You could specify this as a HashTable entry on the Format-Table -Property array e.g.

```
Format-Table -Property NetConnectionID,@{Label='Speed(GB)'; Expression = {$_.Speed/1GB}}
```

Comment: A nice answer! I'd remove the `-ne $null` parts.

Comment: There are actually quite a few entries returned for the Win32_NetworkAdapter class, check it out. I'm using the -ne $null to filter out entries so I can see the actual entries for real physical cards but you can adapt as you see fit.

Comment: [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() works against the local machine only.

Comment: I think Jay is saying that the filter could be simplified to `Where {$_.Speed -and $_.MACAddress}`. As long is neither are 0 or $false, that simplified predicate will work just fine.  Besides you would probably want to filter out a value of 0 anyway.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks. I clearly have a way to go with my PowerShell syntax.

Comment: I'm wondering if keeping the -ne $null has some value in being explicit over the terse syntax.

Comment: It obviously will allow a value of 0 then, too. That should be the only difference.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Windows 8/Server 2012, you can try `Get-NetAdapter` and several more specialized commands like `Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter

You can also use the more comprehensive WMI class `MSFT_NetAdapter` to create customized output. `MSFT_NetAdapter` is described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh968170(v=VS.85).aspx

Here's a command to list the speed and other properties of enabled (State 2), connected (OperationalStatusDownMediaDisconnected $false), 802.3 wired (NdisPhysicalMedium 14), non-virtual adapters on the local computer:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace Root\StandardCimv2 -Class MSFT_NetAdapter | `
  Where-Object { $_.State -eq 2 -and $_.OperationalStatusDownMediaDisconnected -eq $false -and `
                 $_.NdisPhysicalMedium -eq 14 -and $_.Virtual -eq $false } | `
  Format-Table Name,Virtual,State,NdisPhysicalMedium, `
  @{Label='Connected'; Expression={-not $_.OperationalStatusDownMediaDisconnected}}, `
  @{Label='Speed(MB)'; Expression = {$_.Speed/1000000}}, `
  FullDuplex,InterfaceDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

My current version, taking out bluetooth and wireless cards (run with powershell -file script.ps1):

```
# return network speed as exit code

$speed = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter | 
where { $_.speed -and $_.macaddress -and 
$_.name -notmatch 'wireless|wi-fi|bluetooth|802\.11' } | select -expand speed
exit $speed/1000000
```