# Why "root\\StandardCimv2" in Windows 7 doesn't work?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, combobox, wmi

workWhen i try show list with adapters name in combobox like this:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\StandardCimv2","SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetAdapter");
           foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            try
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(queryObj["Name"].ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add("");
            }

         }
```

All good...because used Windows 8. If i run app on PC with Windows 7 i get error:

> System.Management.ManagementException: Invalid namespace

Later I noticed one thing...if this line code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\StandardCimv2","SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetAdapter")
```

Replace on this:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter");
```

The error disappears and everything works. And now Question! 
Why this "root\StandardCimv2" not work in Win7? But with this "root\CIMV2" all good.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the simple and obvious reason, the WMI classes in this namespace (MSFT_Yadayada) are documented to be available only in Windows 8 and Server 2012.  Just look at the bottom of the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant, Really wmi class what i use not support Win7. What now to do? If use this "root\CIMV2" I'll not get what i want. There is not shown the name of the connection, only the name model of the device network card or Wi-fi (Killer e2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller" or "Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 135).

Answer (score 0):

The [Win32_NetworkAdapter class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter) works on Vista and 7.

This answer has an example of using it (in PowerShell) to retrieve Name and connection Speed:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002568/550712

It looks like it also has the "Name" property so it might work as a direct replacement in your code.